# MySQL find missing gaps in a sequence of value

Tags: mysql

I'm tried without success in mysql to get a missing gaps into a list, but i don't know how.

My data is:

```
Cuenta
----------
A01
A02
A03
A05
A08
A10
```

I need to get the following result:

```
Cuenta
----------
A04
A06
A07
A09
```

Thanks!

Comment: What about A00? A11? A99?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: "I'm tried without success..."  I don't see any code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate a temporary table with all values from your desired sequence, you may use prepared statements like this:

```
SET @n = 10;
set @i = 1;
-- query to generate sequence
SET @t = CONCAT('SELECT 1 AS n', REPEAT(' UNION ALL SELECT @i := @i + 1', @n - 1));
-- query to insert sequence into temporary table
SET @s = CONCAT("CREATE TABLE tmp SELECT CONCAT('A', LPAD(n, 2, 0)) AS Cuenta FROM (", @t, ") t");
PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Your temporary table would look like this:

```
+--------+
| Cuenta |
+--------+
| A01    |
| A02    |
| A03    |
| A04    |
| A05    |
| A06    |
| A07    |
| A08    |
| A09    |
| A10    |
+--------+
```

And now you can join both tables and find what you're looking for:

```
SELECT tmp.Cuenta
FROM tmp
LEFT JOIN tbl ON tbl.Cuenta = tmp.Cuenta
WHERE tbl.Cuenta IS NULL
;
```

Result will be:

```
+--------+
| Cuenta |
+--------+
| A04    |
| A06    |
| A07    |
| A09    |
+--------+
```

**DISCLAIMER**: This approach works perfectly for small datasets, but for huge datasets unfortunately behaviour is undetermined.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT A.val
FROM (
    SELECT CONCAT('A', LPAD((@var_i := @var_i + 1), 2, 0)) val
    FROM (SELECT @var_i := 0) A0
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT NULL UNION ALL SELECT NULL) A1 -- 2^1
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT NULL UNION ALL SELECT NULL) A2 -- 2^2
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT NULL UNION ALL SELECT NULL) A3 -- 2^3
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT NULL UNION ALL SELECT NULL) A4 -- 2^4
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT NULL UNION ALL SELECT NULL) A5 -- 2^5
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT NULL UNION ALL SELECT NULL) A6 -- 2^6
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT NULL UNION ALL SELECT NULL) A7 -- 2^7
    LIMIT 99 -- 2^7 > 99 > 2^6, length 2 table should be cross joined at least 7 times
) A
LEFT JOIN `table` t ON A.val = t.Cuenta
WHERE t.Cuent IS NULL
;
```

Comment: Eh? You've lost me

Comment: @Strawberry added comments. Could you elaborate if necessary?